# An antonym for “converse”

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

Suppose you are proving $p \leftrightarrow q$. In your first paragraph you prove $p \rightarrow q$. Your second paragraph begins, “For the converse, assume $q$ holds.”

In this situation, we have a very precise way of referring to the statement $q \rightarrow p$: “the converse.” But we have no good way to refer to $p\rightarrow q$. Sometimes we say “the forward implication,” but I am not a big fan of this phrase and am wondering if there is a single latinate word which means the same thing. (Obverse? Inverse? Contrapositive? No, none of those mean “$p \rightarrow q$.”)

Granted, the word “converse” only works in context, since you are implicitly saying “the converse to $p \rightarrow q$,” and that context can only be inferred if you are using the word “converse” right after you have proven “$p \rightarrow q$.” But, anyway, I am simply asking if there is a better way to say “the forward implication.”

Comment: What would such an antonym mean? In which context would it be used?

Comment: Equivalent, converse, inverse and contrapositive. Maybe one of these satisfies your interests.

Comment: You can just directly say "the statement"

Comment: If you’re starting with $P\Longrightarrow Q$, then it’s an (or the) implication. *Its* converse is the implication in the opposite direction. But something is a converse only in relation to a previously stated implication. So if you’re starting with $P\Longleftarrow Q$, that’s not a converse, it’s an (or the) implication.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Suppose we are proving $p \leftrightarrow q$. The second paragraph of the proof would begin “For the converse, assume $q$.” What is the analogous sentence you could use to begin the first paragraph? “To prove the ___, suppose $p$ holds.”

Comment: In direct reference to your response to @HenningMakholm, I would start the whole proof with the words, “Suppose $p$ holds.”

Comment: @Lubin I totally agree that “converse” is a purely relative term. There is no such thing as THE converse, and when you write “the converse” in a proof, what you’re referring to is the converse of whatever implication you were talking about previously. But see my comment above for an explanation of what I’m looking for.

Comment: @Lubin In response to your last comment: Of course, everyone would and should start their proof that way. That was just a contrived example for the purpose of delineating the concept that I am asking for a word for. I have, however, had real experiences where I wanted a word for that concept. It could happen if you need to discuss the logical outline of a proof—if, for example, you need to justify why a proof wasn’t circular—and you need to talk about multiple implications in different directions at the same time.

Comment: Well, yes, I guess I see your point. Then appropriate words might be “the direct implication” or “the original”. Once upon a time one used the words “necessary” and “sufficient”, but nobody seems ever to have known which was which.

Comment: "The forward implication" is the best you can do here, I think. Anything else is likely to be open to misinterpretation. Why don't you like it?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need a special word? If you are proving $P\iff Q$ you can just talk about *the statement* $P\implies Q$ and its converse.

If you think about it, the converse (and inverse, and contrapositive, and negation) all implicitly refer to the original statement. It is not just "the converse" it is "the converse *of the statement*."

You can't get around establishing what the statement is before you start saying "converse", so there is no sense avoiding it, and there does not really seem to be any evidence more terminology is needed for it, either.

Even if you don't buy that argument for some reason, you should still consider the possibility you are not using the words as they were intended. "Converse" is not really a label for $Q\implies P$, it is a statement about changing an existing statement, just like negation, inversion, and contraposition are. Would one similarly ask "what is the antonym of the contrapositive?" Probably not.

This is supported by the presentation on the wiki article on contraposition, where contraposition, inversion and conversion and negation are all thought of as things you can do to a given statement.

Comment: See the comment thread above. But also “the statement” couldn’t work because it’s ambiguous. If you’re proving $p \leftrightarrow q$, then does “the statement” refer to the statement you’re trying to prove, or the forward implication ($p \rightarrow q$)?

Comment: Sometimes I use "the conditional $p \rightarrow q$ and its converse $q \rightarrow p$".

Comment: @ZachBlumenstein My response is: I don't see the need for a word ( which we are probably showing here does not even exist) to complete a contrived sample sentence. It is all perfectly avoidable by rewriting in one of many simple ways people have already described.

Answer (score 2):

It's not as nice as a simple statement but in each paragraph you can refer to the other p->q or q->p as the converse. I.e. the converse of the converse is the original.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen in some proofs of $P\iff Q$:

"First, we prove *the direct*…

Where $P\implies Q$ is the direct.

Answer (score 1):

(Prove) (the) "implication", "direction" or "direct implication" $p \to q$